# Freeradius doesn't respond to client - ignoring request to auth address ... unknown client

Tags: linux, cisco, freeradius, radius

So trying to setup a simple RADIUS authentication for a CISCO 2600 and [freeradius -X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iamgd.png)

The message says that the client is unknown but still the client conf looks like this:

```
client R1{
    ipaddr = 10.1.1.10
        secret = secretkey
        shortname = R1
        nastype = cisco
}

client radnetwork{
    ipaddr = 10.1.1.0
    netmask = 24
        secret = secretkey
        shortname = radnetwork

}

client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    secret = secretkey
        shortname = localhost
    nastype = other
}
```

I've made sure to chmod 777 both clients.conf and users and because it did drove me crazy and at first the permissions were wrong.

Running radtest locally `radtest myuser mysecret localhost 1812` gets me:

```
(0) No reply from server for ID 168 socket 3
```

and in the log:

```
Dropping packet without response because of error: Received packet from 127.0.0.1 without response because of error: Received packet from 127.0.0.1 with invalid Message-Authenticator! (shared secret is incorrect.)
```

even as the secret ins VERY simple and it is set that way everywhere in this lab.

Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  Your title suggests you have an unknown client, i.e. you've not provided a client definition for the client contacting the server, but the question content is about a mismatched shared secret.

I'll answer the mismatched shared secret part. It may be that figuring that out resolves your other issue.

The posted radtest command is invalid and missing the secret, which is frustrating as the secret is the subject of this question.

As a first step you should run radsniff with the `-s` option to specify the expected secret, and verify that the User-Password attribute it shown correctly in plaintext.

Next, ensure unprintable characters aren't being inserted into the secret in your client definitions by wrapping the secret in double quotes.

Verify that the clients.conf file you're editing is actually being read by introducing a syntax error (just add an extra right hand curly brace '}' at the end) and restarting FreeRADIUS.

Note: For all changes to the server config, you need to restart FreeRADIUS.

This is a common issue.  It's never the code, it's nearly always one of the conditions above.